# Creating a black filter for a custom ShaderEffect

Tags: c#, wpf, hlsl

I am using [this code example](http://khason.net/blog/brightness-and-contrast-manipulation-in-wpf-35-sp1/) to adjust brightness and contrast on a BitmapImage for my WPF app.  The relevant bit of HLSL code is this:

```
sampler2D input : register(s0);
float brightness : register(c0);
float contrast : register(c1);

float4 main(float2 uv : TEXCOORD) : COLOR
{
    float4 color = tex2D(input, uv); 
    float4 result = color;
    result = color + brightness;
    result = result * (1.0+contrast)/1.0;

    return result;
}
```

What I would like to do is add something to filter out low intensity pixels- the idea is that I want to say that any part of the image (I'm just guessing I have to do this per pixel) is below a certain threshold, make it black.  I'm trying to filter out greys a low intensity stuff to make the lighter parts pop out more (this is a greyscale image).  I would then use a slider to adjust that threshold.

I just have no idea if this is a filter or what, was was hoping it's just a simple mod to the code above.  Total n00b to HLSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sampler2D input : register(s0);
float threshold : register(c0);
float4 blankColor : register(c1);

float4 main(float2 uv : TEXCOORD) : COLOR
{
    float4 color = tex2D(input, uv);
    float intensity = (color.r + color.g + color.b) / 3;

    float4 result;
    if (intensity < threshold)
    {
        result = blankColor;
    }
    else
    {
        result = color;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the function name be main(), not threshold() ?

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternate approach to @Ed version.

This takes an input of any color and replaces the original color with black.

```
/// <class>AdjustToBlack</class>
/// <description>An effect that makes pixels of a particular color black.</description>

sampler2D inputSampler : register(S0);


/// <summary>The color that becomes black.</summary>
/// <defaultValue>Green</defaultValue>
float4 ColorKey : register(C0);

/// <summary>The tolerance in color differences.</summary>
/// <minValue>0</minValue>
/// <maxValue>1</maxValue>
/// <defaultValue>0.3</defaultValue>
float Tolerance : register(C1);

float4 main(float2 uv : TEXCOORD) : COLOR
{
   float4 color = tex2D( inputSampler, uv );

   if (all(abs(color.rgb - ColorKey.rgb) < Tolerance)) {
      color.rgb = 0;
   }

   return color;
}
```

Example is from one of the sample shaders included in Shazzam . Note, the /// comments are custom tags, used in the [Shazzam Shader Editor](http://shazzam-tool.com/)