# WPF trying to use pixelshader to disable certain channels

Tags: wpf, shader

I'm trying to use a pixel shader to disable specific channels on an image. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get my shader to work, nor do I know how to do step-through debugging on this. I've tried PIX for windows, but haven't gotten any success with that tool.

Here's my shader file: ChannelEffect .fx

```
sampler2D implicitInputSampler : register(S0);

float4 main(float2 uv : TEXCOORD) : COLOR
{
// Get the source color
float4 color = tex2D(implicitInputSampler, uv);


color.g = 0.0f;
color.b = 0.0f;
// Return new color
return color;
}
```

Right now I'm hard-coding the channels I'm disabling, just to test it. This sample should make only the red channel appear.

```
            ChannelEffect channelEffect = GetChannelEffect(displayChannel);
            image.Effect = channelEffect;


            dc.DrawImage(image.Source, destRect);
```

The end result I get is that the image renders as normal. Its as if I'm not even applying a shader at all. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was [doing something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21034898/creating-a-black-filter-for-a-custom-shadereffect)- and found [Shazzam](http://shazzam-tool.com/) which is a fantastic program that not only will allow you to tweak and twiddle with shaders but will even generate code for you.  I didn't use that code myself, but it gives a great example on *how* to use shaders with C# and XAML.

You can even import your own images to test with until you get your shader code exactly right.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to use that, but their website requires you to give them your email so that they can email you a download link. I'm still waiting on that email.

Comment: I didn't have any problems with the download- maybe I got lucky :)

Comment: I was able to find another a download page:http://shazzam.software.informer.com/download/, not Shazzam's website. Another thing I found was that my shader had to be assigned in xaml, not in code.

Comment: This was quite helpful in solving my problem.